# What book/guide should I follow for GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I searched a lot on the web without coming to a real solution and if I ask this it's because I really have difficulties getting an answer. I need to learn well GLSL 1.20 with OpenGL 2.1.

I have bought beginning OpenGL game programming, 2nd edition, but it talk too little about GLSL. So I'm following some tutorials like [this one](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/directional-lights-i/), but it just makes a lot of examples without explaining the theory.

The problem is that if I want to know something, I have to search a lot, and often the thing that I'm searching doesn't come straightforward. For example I didn't know how to compute the direction between two points, I looked into some example codes and I discovered that it was done with the dot product just by seeing the example code. But with this approach I waste a lot of time. I need a book/guide which tells me how to do basilar stuff and also explains the theory. I just feel like I'm travelling into the fog. What book/guide would you suggest?

Comment: In my humble opinion the best book for learning modern GLSL http://www.packtpub.com/opengl-4-0-shading-language-cookbook/book?tag=rk/opengl4-abr6/0811

Comment: I second the above comment. From what you explain it seems you’d also need something like [this book](http://www.mathfor3dgameprogramming.com/) (don’t pay attention to the ugly cover; the content is excellent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard reference for GLSL would be referred to as the orange book. Located here on amazon.

[http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-Shading-Language-3rd-Edition/dp/0321637631/ref=pd_bxgy_b_text_y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321637631)

*edit* geeze i'm out of it today. Here is the link to the correct book.